# How to write 2 forms validations in single ts file using Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am new to Angular 2.

We have 2 forms in the HTML with separate div tags, whenever 1st `div` executed, the 2nd `div` is false state. Whenever the success calls back the second `div` will be true state. Whenever it comes 2nd `div` true state it will display [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOkv0.png).

Below is my .ts file code:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
            public navParams: NavParams,
            public formBuilder:FormBuilder,
            public logger: Logger,
            public rest: Rest
            ) {
  this.customer_id=this.navParams.get('customer_id');
  this.mobile=this.navParams.get('mobile');

  this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
    'otpNumber': ['', Validators.required]
    //'password': ['', Validators.required]
   });

  this.myForm1 = formBuilder.group({
    'newpassword': ['', Validators.required],
    'conformPassword': ['', Validators.required]
  });

  this.getotp();
}

submit(){
  let validateOTPObj = {
    loginId: this.mobile,
    otp:this.myForm.value.otpNumber
  }

  this.logger.debug("checking the otpNumber"+JSON.stringify(validateOTPObj));

  this.rest.post('/validateOTP' ,validateOTPObj)
    .subscribe((result)=>{
      this.logger.debug("checking data of success " + JSON.stringify(result));

       if(result.status=='1'){
         //this.navCtrl.push(,{});
         //this.access_token = id;
         this.firstDiv=false;
         this.secondDiv = true;
         this.logger.debug("checking access tocken "+ this.access_token);
         alert("otp success");
       } else {
         this.logger.info("error");
       }
    });
 }
```

Comment: can you share the html side?

Comment: it would be better if you share your html but based on the error message maybe you've just forgot to declare myForm/myForm1 as formGroup in html `[formGroup]="myForm"  [formGroup]="myForm1"`

Answer (score 0):

Just call different method for different forms:

HTML:

```
 <form (submit)= 'form1()'>
<input type='text'  required >
<input type='submit' value='submit' />
```

```
 <form (submit)= 'form2()'>
<input type='text'  required >
<input type='submit' value='submit' />
```

TS:

```
  form1(){
console.log('form 1')
  }

 form2(){
console.log('form 2')
  }
```